# Applebot not crawling sitemap.xml

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

On our website we noticed that the Applebot is not crawling our sitemap.xml, so it is unaware of most of our internal webpages.

We have no robots.txt restrictions for that bot, on the contrary we tried to whitelist it, and there is a Sitemap field containing the sitemap URL as you can see below.

Are we doing anything wrong in robots.txt which is blocking it from crawling our sitemap.xml?

Here's our robots.txt looks like, with minor changes such as replacing our domain with example.com:

```
## Disallow ALL
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Crawl-delay: 600

## but allow only important bots
User-agent: Applebot
User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
User-agent: msnbot
User-agent: msnbot-media
User-agent: Slurp
User-agent: Yahoo-Blogs
User-agent: Yahoo-MMCrawler
User-agent: Yandex

## disallow directories
Disallow: /dir1/
Disallow: /dir2/
## disallow files
Disallow: /status
Disallow: /health

## disallow some text file extensions
Disallow: /*.txt$
Disallow: /*.json$

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
Host: example.com
```

Comment: Have you tested your robots.txt with an online tool such as http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/ I did a quick search and do not see immediate references for applebot reading sitemaps. Do you know if applebot does read sitemaps? Have you added your sitemap to robots.txt using the code found here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: Yes, my file seems to be according to the spec.

Comment: Have you added your sitemap to robots.txt? That may help.

Comment: Why do you need Applebot to know about all your pages?

Answer (score 1):

A single typo looks to be causing this issue.

Your `disallow: /` statement is blocking all robots. It should show up as `disallow:`

Here is a rewritten version of your robots.txt file to allow robots to access your sitemap...

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /dir1
Disallow: /dir2
Disallow: /status
Disallow: /health

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

[@PlanetScale](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/60702/)

Since the default for URLs is 'index' (for Google, at least), why leave a blank line in `robots.txt` with regards to `Disallow:`?

I'd omit it before I'd specify it.

Answer (score -1):

Keep these lines at last.

```
## Disallow ALL
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Crawl-delay: 600
```

Comment: Surely you jest. You are recommending that they disallow all user agents, to the home directory and below with a 600ms delay. If you are disallowing all user agents from the domain home level and depper, why would a crawl delay matter?l? This is why you shouldn't outsource SEO.

Comment: @adam-asdf. Thank you for your pointer. I am new to SEO. I do not take outsourced projects and neither I am planning to take in the future. May be my answer is wrong. You should stop generalizing.